# Add packets to array

Tags: java, arrays, packets

I made method which should give another packet value * 2 while array index < 4. Then it should give packet value * 3 until space from disc is out. Where did i make a mistake in my code? thanks.

```js
    public static void addPacketsToTable(byte[] byteTable, long packetSize, long diskSpace) throws IOException {
        long packet = fetchPacketSize();//size of packet (it is 5)
        long space = fetchDiskSpace();//free space on my disk
        for(int i = 0; i < byteTable.length; i++) {//for another packet
            while(packet < space && byteTable[i] < 4) {
                packet *= 2;
                while(byteTable[i] > 4) {
                    packet *= 3;
                }
                System.out.println(packet);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you give more context. I have actually no idea what your code is supposed to do; or what it is supposed to be used for ...

Comment: the idea is to multiply packet value *2 from index 0 to 4, and then to multiple this value *3 till free space will be gone

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the problem, a simple solution can be:

```
public static void addPacketsToTable(byte[] byteTable, long packetSize, long diskSpace) throws IOException {

    long packet = fetchPacketSize(); //size of packet (it is 5)
    long space = fetchDiskSpace(); //free space on my disk

    for (int i = 0; i < byteTable.length; i++) { //for another packet

        if (i < 4)
            packet *= 2;
        else
            packet *= 3;

        // packet size overflows disk
        if (packet > space)
            break;

        System.out.println(packet);

    }
}
```

Comment: well i made a mistake now i see that. i need index, not value from index... my fault. how should i fix it? is there a solution?